Haproxy hot reloads on HTTP2
I was wondering if hot-reloads will work in an HTTP2 (GRPC) environment. Long lived connections don’t behave like regular old http and my experiments so far have been unsuccessful. Connections are not migrated gracefully to the new haproxy (2.4) process which is something I cannot afford.
I’ve have also noticed that the old process never stops, after the hot reload I see two haproxy processes and it never stops.
I've tried with systemctl reload haproxy while having a connection between my grpc clients and servers going through it.

Based on what you said, it seems the old haproxy process continues to run to handle the old connections to avoid seeing failures. You may need to configure MAX_CONNECTION_AGE on your grpc servers to put an upper limit on the connection lifetime to let the old haproxy process exit.
